# Select an hour interval between two date SQL Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm writing a trigger for an online videogame project for my university, and this trigger was intended for putting an advertising after 8 hours of game (with a DBMS Output on the trigger I guess).

But i'm having trouble calculate this difference :

For example, I got :

```
LOGINDATE              LOGOUTDATE
--------------------   --------------------
15-MAG-2017 23:15:42   16-MAG-2017 02:15:54
```

In the trigger I would like to take the total amount of hours subtracting it from LOGINDATE-LOGOUTDATE, and saving that into a variabile MAX_HOURS that will do the trick into an IF STATEMENT ( IF MAX_HOURS > 8, for example )

Is there some way to do this ?

Comment: Why are you having trouble with the calculation - what are you currently doing, and what is wrong with it? (Also, not sure this makes sense; what is the triggering even supposed to be? Are you showing something when they log out if they have been logged in for more than 8 hours?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example:

```
select (LOGOUTDATE - LOGINDATE)*24 
INTO MAX_HOURS 
        from your_table;
```

result of date subtraction is in units of days.  Multiply to 24 hours to get units of hours.

Comment: Oh my god , it worked like a charms! i would like to UP this comment but i dont have the reputation to do that yet!

Thank you very much for your kindness, but i have two question : How this hour_diff works ? never heard about that.

second question : is there a way to round the results of this query ? ( example : from 3,00333 to 3 )

Comment: Yes, if you subtract two date fields whose difference is not a whole #days, then the result contains a fraction also.  You can use oracle ROUND function .  See this tutorial https://www.akadia.com/services/ora_date_time.html

Comment: @Asynchronousx - you can still [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you want to, even if you can't up-vote yet.